# Touchpad delay after typing

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, asus-laptop

Whenever I type and try to move the cursor with the touchpad, I notice there is a small delay and the cursor won't move until about one second after a key is pressed on the keyboard. I checked my devices under device manager and it says that I have an ASUS Precision Touchpad. Is there any way to eliminate the delay?

Answer (score 3):

Palm detection is enabled in your touchpad settings.

Turning it off will eliminate the delay.

To do so, go to :
Control Panel >Mouse>Touchpad Settings> Palm Detection

And then change value to a smaller value, like 0.2

Comment: How do I get to the touchpad settings? I've tried to access it before but I can't. Unless you're talking about the windows 10 touchpad settings page.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5gZE2_7gJs

Comment: When I click additional settings, it just leads me to the settings for the wireless mouse I have.

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/How-to-disable-quot-Smartsense-quot-on-Synaptics-Touchpad/m-p/5577594/highlight/true#M130101

Comment: I don't have a Synaptics touchpad. It says I have an ASUS Precision Touchpad

Comment: There are two companies that make touchpads for PCs: [Synaptics](https://www.synaptics.com/), and [Alps](http://www.alps.com/gps_e/). Everything else is a rebrand.

Comment: Ok but when I go to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software there is nothing titled Alps or Synaptics

Comment: I found something else claiming that a touchpad driver update could help, but haven't been able to find anything else useful.

Comment: I just found out my touchpad name:ELAN/SA473I-12A4